# Start non-GUI application after network connection is up and running

Tags: linux, debian, raspbian

I'm using Raspbian, which is based on Debian. My Raspberry automatically boots into the desktop. I have a small program written in C and compiled with g++ as executable. The program needs a running network connection and outputs some data to the terminal. Nothing fancy.

To use it, I have to open a LXterminal window and run the program manually with sudo rights

```
sudo ./Desktop/rpiMainProgram
```

My question is: How do I automatically start a terminal based program after a network connection is established?

---

I use [wvdial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wvdial) to connect a 3G dongle automatically via `/etc/network/interface`. The connection works. I can ping and surf

```
auto ppp0
iface ppp0 inet wvdial
```

<sup>I followed [this tutorial](http://www.sbprojects.com/projects/raspberrypi/mobile.php) to set up wvdial if it matters</sup>

I [saw a method](http://www.sbprojects.com/projects/raspberrypi/tweetmyip.php) which uses the `post-up` method in `/etc/network/interfaces` to call a bash (?) script. But I couldn't get this method to run a non-GUI application

My last attempt before I gave up was

```
auto ppp0
iface ppp0 inet wvdial
post-up LXterminal "sudo ./Desktop/rpiMainProgram"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put something like this in your `/etc/rc.local` file (untested):

```
{ while ! ping -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8; do  sleep 1; done; /home/youruser/Desktop/rpiMainProgram > /home/youruser/Desktop/rpiMainProgram.log 2>&1; }&
```

`ping -c 1 -W 1 8.8.8.8`: sends out one ping packet and waits 1 second for its return

The `while` loop continues as long as the `ping` command exits with a status code >0, meaning, as long as it fails.

When you have a network connection and can ping `8.8.8.8` successfully the loop will stop and execute your program (check if calling it like this makes a difference, for example with the `pwd`).

With the `{}` we make it into a singular command kind of thing, so that we can push the whole thing into the background using `&`. Otherwise it would block the rest of `/etc/rc.local` until you have a network.

There might be more elegant solutions, but I have something similar to that on my Pi.

Comment: The C program is a non-GUI program which outputs to stout via printf. Will I be able to view that output (in a terminal) after starting the xdesktop as user pi?

Comment: @nixda No you won't, but you can redirect the output (+ stderr) into a file and look at it later, or track it in a terminal via `tail -f /home/youruser/Desktop/rpiMainProgram.log`. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Start your program in a terminal multiplexer such as [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux). Use it to create a detached terminal where you run your program, and attach to that terminal when you want to interact with it. For example, with screen, run this during startup:

```
screen -S rpiMainProgram -d -m /home/nixda/Desktop/rpiMainProgram
```

and use this to attach to the screen instance where the program runs:

```
screen -S rpiMainProgram -r -d
```

To detach from the screen instance, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd>.

On Debian, to run a program after a network interface is enabled, [add a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&sektion=5). You'll need to check which interface is being brought up (in praticular you don't want to start the program when the loopback interface is started). Create `/etc/network/if-up.d/local_rpiMainProgram` containing something like

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$IFACE" in
  ppp0) screen -S rpiMainProgram -d -m /home/nixda/Desktop/rpiMainProgram
esac
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
if ping -q -W1 -c1 8.8.8.8; then
  screen -S rpiMainProgram -d -m /home/nixda/Desktop/rpiMainProgram
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rungetty to run it on a unused virtual terminal would work quite nicely. control alt f*n* to view the output.